# How to write the rewrite js, css, img rule for domain and IP address by reusing the current rule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

This is my current rule

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ public/     [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This rule will rewrite all url to public folder

www.xxx.com/js/main.js -> www.xxx.com/public/js/main.js

123.123.123.123/site_folder/js/main.js -> 123.123.123.123/site_folder/public/js/main.js

Now I want to add some rules for js, css, img

e.g.

```
src="/js/main.js"
src="/css/main.css"
src="/img/test/png"
```

When URL is domain, no need to rewrite "www.xxx.com"

```
src="/js/main.js" -> www.xxx.com/js/main.js
```

If URL is IP, rewrite to site folder URL "123.123.123.123/site_folder"

```
src="/js/main.js" -> 123.123.123.123/site_folder/js/main.js
```

After the first rewrite, use this current rule to rewrite again

```
RewriteRule ^$ public/     [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]

www.xxx.com/js/main.js -> www.xxx.com/public/js/main.js
123.123.123.123/site_folder/js/main.js -> 123.123.123.123/site_folder/public/js/main.js
```

So that I just need to modify the current if I rename the public folder.

Is it possible to do all above?

Comment: What is `/site_folder/` and where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: 123.123.123.123/site_folder/ = public_html/site_folder/, and the .htaccess location is public_html/site_folder/.htaccess

Comment: Ok is `123.123.123.123/site_folder/` same as `www.xxx.com/site_folder/`?

Comment: No, because in the virtual host, www.xxx.com is pointed to public_html/site_folder/, so www.xxx.com will access to the root of application folder

Answer (score 0):

Place this rule in `/public_html/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(js|css|img)/.+$ /site_folder%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R=302]
```

Place this rule in `/public_html/site_folder/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```